# Проблема с выпадающим списком в IE

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять почему сайт плохо отображается в ie. http://test-10licei.ucoz.ru/

Comment: А вы считаете, что в остальных браузерах, сайт "хорошо отображается"? ))) А вообще, я сам удивлен, ведь ucoz вообще не должен нигде отображаться, за исключением IE версий старше 5-ой.

Comment: Я тоже так думаю, но попросили сделать именно под ucoz, мол там cms "хорошая"...

Comment: На вашем месте, я бы просто пожелал успехов таким заказчикам и телефон их пометил, как "опасный для карьерного роста"

Comment: потому что и е не понимает большинство тегов и атрибутов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из стиля

```
ul.menu li ul{
    margin-top:5px - убрать
}
```

в стиле

```
ul.menu li:hover ul{
    top: 34px; заменить на  top:100%;
}
```

и в стиле

```
ul.menu li:hover ul li{
    width: 150px; - убрать или заменить на width:100%;
}
```

ну и дальше пилить и пилить))) удачи